# Floating Point Exception (Core Dumped) while doing division in assembly

Tags: linux, exception, assembly, x86, integer-division

I'm trying to add 2 two-digit numbers which are bound to yield a two-digit or three-digit number.

Here's what I have so far, and when I try to print the carry, it says *Floating Point Exception (Core Dumped)*

```
section .data
    msg db "Enter 2 numbers: "
    msgLen equ $-msg

section .bss
    numa1 resb 1
    numa2 resb 1
    numb1 resb 1
    numb2 resb 1
    carry resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start: 
    ;print message
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, msgLen
    int 80h

    ;accept first number (1st digit)
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, numa1
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    ;accept first number (2nd digit)
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, numa2
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h

    ;accept second number (1st digit)
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, numb1
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    ;accept second number (2nd digit)
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, numb2
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h

    ;character to number conversion
    sub byte[numa1], 30h
    sub byte[numa2], 30h
    sub byte[numb1], 30h
    sub byte[numb2], 30h
    sub byte[carry], 30h

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ;add ones digit
    mov al, [numa2]
    add byte[numb2], al
    add byte[numb2], 30h

    ;get carry of sum of ones digit
    mov ax, [numb2]
    mov byte[carry], 10
    div byte[carry]

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, carry
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h


    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

---

```
  carry
  numa1   numa2
+ numb2   numb2
---------------
          numb2

where numb2 = numb2 % 10
      carry = numb2 / 10
```

Comment: what OS is this? Linux?

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention sorry. 32bit Linux

Comment: What line generates the exception? What are the parameters to the instruction that raised the exception? Note that there are implied parameters to some instructions.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [On which platforms does integer divide by zero trigger a floating point exception?](//stackoverflow.com/q/37262572) and / or [8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/a/43575674).  DIV overflow -> SIGFPE

Answer (score 1):

First, [`xor ebx, ebx` is shorter and faster than `mov ebx, 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/995714)

Also, adding two 1-digit numbers results in a maximum carry of 1 (9 + 9 = 18), so no need to divide, just subtracting the number by 10 is enough. Moreover you should generally avoid 16-bit registers, which is both longer (due to the 66h prefix) and slower (because of the partial register update). That means

```
mov ax, [numb2]
mov byte[carry], 10
div byte[carry]
```

will be much slower than the following

```
movzx eax, word ptr [numb2]
sub   eax, 10
```

But after all, why do you use such a complex way when x86 already has [BCD instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_BCD_opcode) for that purpose. Besides, those instructions have AF and CF for BCD math carry so no need to manage it on your own

You can also use binary math directly and just convert them at input/output. Most of the case the cost of converting is negligible

Answer (score 0):

Note sure about the "Floating Point Exception", but these lines are likely to cause a division overflow:

```
mov ax, [numb2]
mov byte[carry], 10
div byte[carry]
```

You're doing a word move from `numb2` to `ax`, which means that you'll get whatever was stored at `carry` in `ah`. If we assume that the `.bss` section is zeroed at startup, the value at `carry` will be `0xD0` when you load it into `ah`, since you've done `sub byte[carry], 30h`.

Hence, you're dividing `0xD0nn` by 10, which will result in a quotient too large to fit in `al`.

You could replace `mov ax, [numb2]` with `movzx ax,byte [numb2]`.

Comment: Of course, the `sub byte[carry], 30h` is questionable in itself, and should probably be `mov byte[carry], 0` instead... Relying on `carry` to be zero initialized will usually be ok, except when it isn't, with the result that hair gets pulled and teeth gnashed...